# AWS IAM Trust Policy - Allow only one resource to sts:AssumeRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions

Let's say the ARN of my State Machine is `arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:stateMachine:resource-1`.
It has IAM role configured with some permissions and it's current **trust policy** is following:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:stateMachine:resource-1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The **Condition** specified in above **trust policy** is not working as I expect. My State Machine is not able to assume this IAM Role, however it works when I change like below, but there's no restriction to particular resource:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnLike": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:stateMachine:*"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

My goal is to allow only this particular resource (`arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:stateMachine:resource-1`) to assume this particular IAM role. All resources are in the same AWS Account.

I can't understand why the first **trust policy** doesn't work. Even AWS Documentation for Step Functions is showing it as an example: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/procedure-create-iam-role.html#prevent-cross-service-confused-deputy

Comment: The docs only use `ArnLike`, there is no mention of `ArnEquals` on the linked example. The problem here might very well be that the resource is not assuming the role but e.g. the step function execution. Maybe try `arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:execution:resource-1:*` !?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It may be good direction, unfortunately `arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789123:execution:resource-1:*` with `ArnLike` is not assuming the role too.

Comment: Is it failing to create the state machine or failing the execution when you attempt to run a Task? In both places it attempts to assume the role.

Comment: It is failing the execution when I attempt to run.